# Can you not log into a created user if the PASSWORD EXPIRE statement is involved?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
DROP USER U1JakeScanlan;
DROP USER U2JakeScanlan;
DROP PROFILE PJakeScanlan;
DROP ROLE R1JakeScanlan;
DROP TABLE USER1DATA;
DROP TABLE USER2DATA;

CREATE PROFILE PJakeScanlan LIMIT
PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION ORA12C_VERIFY_FUNCTION
SESSIONS_PER_USER 3
FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS 4
PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME 120
PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME 1/24
;

SELECT * FROM DBA_profiles where profile = 'PJAKESCANLAN';

CREATE USER U1JakeScanlan
IDENTIFIED BY "blootbad1!"
DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS
QUOTA 30M ON USERS
PROFILE PJakeScanlan
PASSWORD EXPIRE;

CREATE USER U2JakeScanlan
IDENTIFIED BY "Grimmshow2$"
DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS
QUOTA 30M ON USERS
PROFILE PJakeScanlan
PASSWORD EXPIRE;

CREATE ROLE R1JakeScanlan;

GRANT CONNECT TO R1JakeScanlan;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO R1JakeScanlan;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO R1JakeScanlan;

CREATE TABLE USER1DATA(
FOOD VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
LAST4CC VARCHAR(4),
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(20),
LASTNAME VARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE USER2DATA(
AGE INT PRIMARY KEY,
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(20),
LASTNAME VARCHAR(25),
GAMEPURCHASE VARCHAR(35)
);

INSERT INTO USER1DATA(FOOD, LAST4CC, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME)
VALUES('Cheeseburger', 1548, 'Jake', 'Scanlan');
INSERT INTO USER1DATA(FOOD, LAST4CC, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME)
VALUES('Cookies', 8745, 'Bertha', 'Bubbles');
INSERT INTO USER1DATA(FOOD, LAST4CC, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME)
VALUES('Celery Root', 9999, 'Vegana', 'Grassbottom');

INSERT INTO USER2DATA(AGE, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, GAMEPURCHASE)
VALUES(30, 'Jake', 'Scanlan', 'God of War: Ragnarok');
INSERT INTO USER2DATA(AGE, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, GAMEPURCHASE)
VALUES(10, 'Sally', 'Seashells', 'Hello Kitty Island');
INSERT INTO USER2DATA(AGE, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, GAMEPURCHASE)
VALUES(19, 'Neville', 'Longbottom', 'Harry Potter Set');

GRANT R1JakeScanlan to U1JakeScanlan;
GRANT R1JakeScanlan to U2JakeScanlan;

GRANT SELECT ON USER1DATA TO U1JakeScanlan;
GRANT INSERT ON USER1DATA TO U1JakeScanlan;
GRANT SELECT ON USER1DATA TO U2JakeScanlan;
GRANT SELECT ON USER2DATA TO U2JakeScanlan;
```

Trying to log into my user to check and make sure my grants are working but, PASSWORD EXPIRE is preventing that. Since I am still new to Oracle I was wondering if its impossible to log into my users with that statement. My lab specifies the users need the password expire but than asks to log into them. But wasn't told or shown how to log into, with password expire?

Comment: How are you trying to connect - you haven't shown that (or the error/response you get). Some clients or applications may treat the ORA-28001 as an error rather than a warning, but without knowing what you're actually doing or seeing, we can't know if that is the issue. (Also - you seem to be creating tables at the same time as users; if you're doing this as SYS then that isn't a good idea: don't create objects in the built-in schemas.)

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to log into my user to check and make sure my grants are working but, PASSWORD EXPIRE is preventing that.

Looks like you're misinterpreting reality. `password expire` doesn't prevent you to log in - it forces you to change password the first time you log in to the database.

```
SQL> create user jake identified by jake
  2  default tablespace user_data
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on user_data
  5  password expire;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to jake;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect jake/jake@orcl
ERROR:
ORA-28001: the password has expired


Changing password for jake
New password:
Retype new password:
Password changed
Connected.

SQL>
```

See? I established connection with no problem at all.

Comment: ya when I try to log into my user it doesn’t do any of that it just gives me the error “username/password invalid: password expired”.

Comment: @Alex Poole  So I’m just following the order of the lab and that’s what I ended up with. Where I’m trying to connect to my user is in the “add connection” but when I try to connect to the user, I get “username/password invalid: password expired”. Which I have been reading/trying to find where I may have missed that but no luck yet. As far as my users and tables, I’m finding out that my grants don’t seem to be sending the table to the user anyways but maybes that because of like you said, my tables are created at the same time as my user.. If you have any advice.